# Remove outliers and reduce yLim appropriately for each facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am currently making a facet multi box plot using `ggplot2`, where I have cleared the outliers and set the yLim to 5000.

However, not all of the boxplots (the ones at the beginning of the image below) go anywhere near 5000. How can I reduce the y axis for only a select few of these boxplots in the image? I've tried multiple answers from the community, but they seem to be outdated.

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

data_frame <- read.csv("results.csv", header=T)

p <- ggplot(data=data_frame, aes(x='', y=value)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, aes(fill=policy))
p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ level, scales="free") + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5000))
p <- p + xlab("") + ylab("Authorisation Time (ms)") + ggtitle("Title")
ggsave("bplots.png", plot=last_plot(), device=png())
```

Comment: you set the y-axis to `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5000))` so in those first ones you will always have scale up to `5000`. Easiest solution would be to remove data points directly and then use facet with `scales = "free"`

Comment: I am already using `scales="free"` and the `ylim` was only a test. Just using  `scales="free"` still keeps the outliers there..

Comment: You can remove them from the data before plotting it.

Comment: Yes but this is tampering with the raw data in my case. Even so, there are thousands upon thousands of them in many files, so definitely not an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## New to `ggplot2` 3.5.0

There's a new option to do this for you in latest `ggplot2` releases:

```r
library(ggplot2)  

data_frame <- data.frame(value = c(rnorm(2000, mean = 100, sd = 20), rnorm(2000, mean = 1000, sd = 500)),
                         level = c(rep(1,2000), rep(2, 2000)),
                         policy = factor(c(rep(c(rep(1, 500), rep(2, 500), rep(3, 500), rep(4, 500)), 2))))

data_frame |> 
  ggplot(aes(x='', y=value, fill = policy)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outliers = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap( ~ level, scales="free") + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Authorisation Time (ms)") + ggtitle("Title")
```

[image]

## Older versions

As noted above, you pretty much have to filter before plotting, but this doesn't need to be done by editing any files, or even by creating new dataframes. Using `dplyr` you can just chain this into the processing of your data. I've done a hopefully reproducible example below with some made-up data (as I don't have yours). I created a function to filter by the same procedures as the boxplot is using. It's a bit hacky, but hopefully works as one potential solution:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

data_frame <- data.frame(value = c(rnorm(2000, mean = 100, sd = 20), rnorm(2000, mean = 1000, sd = 500)),
           level = c(rep(1,2000), rep(2, 2000)),
           policy = factor(c(rep(c(rep(1, 500), rep(2, 500), rep(3, 500), rep(4, 500)), 2))))

# filtering function - turns outliers into NAs to be removed
filter_lims <- function(x){
  l <- boxplot.stats(x)$stats[1]
  u <- boxplot.stats(x)$stats[5]

  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    x[i] <- ifelse(x[i]>l & x[i]<u, x[i], NA)
  }
  return(x)
}

data_frame %>% 
  group_by(level, policy) %>%  # do the same calcs for each box
  mutate(value2 = filter_lims(value)) %>%  # new variable (value2) so as not to displace first one)
  ggplot(aes(x='', y=value2, fill = policy)) + 
  geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE, coef = 5) +  # remove NAs, and set the whisker length to all included points
  facet_wrap( ~ level, scales="free") + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Authorisation Time (ms)") + ggtitle("Title")
```

Resulting in the following (simplified) plot:

[image: Graph from synthetic data]

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for a solution for this for a long time.